# Found a misspelling in the email from stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, email

I received an email about some activity on a question, and noticed a small misspelling (*chcecked* instead of *checked*) in the email, screenshot below. The guys who I contacted via email said to post in meta, since here developers can track things related to main site (features, bugs, etc).

[image: misspelling]

Comment: Sorry, didn't thought to check for duplicate on this one. Is it ok if I delete it, so it wont be 2 of them?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about deleting it. This one might be closed as a duplicate of the other, but having two different reports might make it easier for others to search for this bug.

Comment: No need to delete. Enjoy the free rep!